# Editar filas de una tabla con jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con JQUERY en mi proyecto en el cual genero una tabla desde una función con AJAX, por cada registro ademas de los datos, genero una columna con un botón para poder editar, el problema es que necesito que al pulsar el boton de edicion; sobre la misma columna del valor (Total Monto), aparezca un input con el valor de este y pueda editarlo desde su mismo sitio. adjunto una imagen de lo que genera mi tabla 
.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito que al dar click a editar, aparezca un input con el monto en este caso 30.00 y pueda editarlo desde ahí.
esta es mi funcion:

```js
function get(){
    var id = $('#Id').val();
    $.ajax({
      url:baseurl+"reserva/get",
      type:"POST",
      data:{id:id},
      success:function(data){
          var registros = eval(data);
          html ="<table class='table'><thead>";
          html +="<tr><th>#</th><th>Total Monto</th><th>Fecha de Registro</th><th>Opciones</th></tr>";
          html +="</thead><tbody>";
          for (var i = 0; i < registros.length; i++) {
            html +="<tr><td>"+registros[i]["contador"]+"</td><td>"+registros[i]["Monto"]+" </td><td>"+registros[i]["Fecha"]+"</td><td><a title='Editar' class='btn btn-sm btn-squared margin-inline'><i class='fa fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td></tr>";
          };
          $("#lista").html(html);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Quieres que el input aparezca en misma tabla o en una ventana modal?

Comment: En la misma tabla,  donde esta el valor 30.00 y que tenga justamente este valor el input tambien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajustar la columna editable, el boton y crear una funcion:

```
function get(){
var id = $('#Id').val();
$.ajax({
  url:baseurl+"reserva/get",
  type:"POST",
  data:{id:id},
  success:function(data){
      var registros = eval(data);
      html ="<table class='table'><thead>";
      html +="<tr><th>#</th><th>Total Monto</th><th>Fecha de Registro</th><th>Opciones</th></tr>";
      html +="</thead><tbody>";
      for (var i = 0; i < registros.length; i++) {
        html +="<tr><td>"+registros[i]["contador"]+"</td><td class='editable'>";
        //modificando columna editable
        html +="<span>"+registros[i]["Monto"]+"</span>"; 
        html +="<input type='hidden' value=''">; 

        html +="</td><td>"+registros[i]["Fecha"]+"</td>";
        //modificando boton
        html +="<td><a onclick='editarFila(this);' title='Editar' class='btn btn-sm btn-squared margin-inline'><i class='fa fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td></tr>";
      };
      $("#lista").html(html);
    }
  }
});
```

}

Luego la funcion:

```
function editarFila(obj){
    var objSpan=$(obj).parent().parent().children('.editable').children('span');
    $(objSpan).css('display','none')
    $(obj).parent().parent().children('.editable').children('input').attr('type','text').val($(objSpan).text());
}
```

Comment: gracias voy a probarla.. haber que tal aunque aun tengo que agregar a esto, algún botón para guardar o cancelar dicha acción, me has dado una buena idea haber como me va.

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas maneras de hacer lo que quieres, aquí te dejo una (partiendo de tu código) de lo que considero es la manera mas sencilla de hacerlo, quedara de tu parte mejorarla.

Ejemplo:

```js
registros = {
 length:3,
 0:{"contador":1,"Monto":30,"Fecha":"2017-09-07 11:51:15"
 },
 1:{"contador":2,"Monto":30,"Fecha":"2017-09-07 11:51:15"
 },
 2:{"contador":3,"Monto":30,"Fecha":"2017-09-07 11:51:15"
 }
}
html ="<table class='table'><thead>";
html +="<tr><th>#</th><th>Total Monto</th><th>Fecha de Registro</th><th>Opciones</th></tr>";
html +="</thead><tbody>";
for (var i = 0; i < registros.length; i++) {
 html +="<tr><td>"+registros[i]["contador"]+"</td><td><input id='edit"+registros[i]["contador"]+"' value='"+registros[i]["Monto"]+"' disabled> </td><td>"+registros[i]["Fecha"]+"</td><td><input type='button' value='Editar' onclick='z=document.getElementById(\"edit"+registros[i]["contador"]+"\");z.disabled=\"\";z.focus();z.select();'><i class='fa fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></td></tr>";
};
$("#lista").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista">
</div>
```

Espero esto te ayuda, Saludos!!! ;))...